# Squid packet injection / replace

Tags: proxy, squid, replace, traffic-shaping

I have a server which will act as a proxy, using squid. My goal is to have something replace outgoing data. I tried ettercap, no luck whatsoever. The idea is, whatever-will-replace-data needs to run alongside with squid on the same box.
Any ideas of a good ettercap replacement ?
Or how would I go about using ettercap with squid on the same box ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using squid that implies you're talking about HTTP. But you're trying to modify the contents at the stram level - if you try to do this at the packet level, that means that you need to build your own TCP stack to decompose/resompose the HTTP stream, **then** implement your own HTTP stack on top of that before you can get acces to the data!

Wouldn't it be a lot simpler to use the TCP and HTTP stacks already available in squid and the OS? [Here's a simple example](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html) of how to modify content using squid.

Comment: It would be alot simpler if I knew Perl :)

Comment: You can write a url redirector in any language you like - it reads URLs on stdin, then outputs the modified version on stdout - the one I referenced just happens to download the content and modify it before pointing the request to the local copy.

Comment: All the solutions above refer to the URL, and none to the actual content injection.

Answer (score 0):

In linux you can use [mitmf](https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/MITMf) for that.

```
mitmf --spoof --arp -i wlan0 --gateway <GATEWAY_IP> --target <TARGET_IP> --replace --search-str "searchstring" --replace-str "replacestring"
```